# How to exclude some Categories from next_post_link and previous_post_link (Wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to exclude some categories from the post navigation (next_post_link and previous_post_link) and it does not work. I need help.

I would like to use the functions.php for this function.

There is a nice function for excluding the categories from the "Category Widget":

```
function ds_exclude_widget_categories($args) {
  $exclude = '1,26,28';
     $args['exclude'] = $exclude;
  return $args;
}
add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'ds_exclude_widget_categories');
```

How could such a function look like to exclude categories from post navigation?

Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

`next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` already have arguments for excluding items https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

So if you want to only exclude category with ID number 13 from your links you should use something like

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', FALSE, '13' ); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Ed Dogan, Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do not want to change the files in the theme and I do not want to create a child-theme. I would like to make it as a filter in functions.php. is that possible?